# Is there an idiom that means to make big claims but have little evidence to support them?

Tags: phrase, idioms

Is there an idiom that means to make big claims but have little evidence to support them?

Comment: Maybe [穿凿附会](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A9%BF%E5%87%BF%E9%99%84%E4%BC%9A) ([YouDao](https://youdao.com/w/穿凿附会)), but I'm not sure.

Comment: [信口雌黄](https://youdao.com/w/%E4%BF%A1%E5%8F%A3%E9%9B%8C%E9%BB%84), [捕风捉影](https://youdao.com/w/%E6%8D%95%E9%A3%8E%E6%8D%89%E5%BD%B1).

Comment: Do you mean "make big claims" about one's own situation, or "make big claims" like conspiracy theories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

空口无凭，言而无据，无根之论

But you can coin four-character words to express it more accurately. It looks like that you mean academic claims.

Let me have a try:

论訇证寡（The claim is thunderous(figurative), but the evidence is little.）

例句：

像他这样的学术投机分子，才敢在会上作论訇证寡的报告。

Note: Only in writing you can coin such words. Otherwise people won't understand you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure If 言过其实 can fit. it means *a statement surpassing the fact*.

or 夸大其词？ it means *represent beyond the bounds of truth; make an overstatement;*

Answer (score 1):

This thread would never be complete without the "urban-dictionary" style (i.e, slang), modern example for such idiom, the good old **`吹牛`**, or its R-rated version **`吹牛逼`**.

It generally means to brag about something, which *could* be true but usually isn't.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to some good answers:

信口开河

夸夸其谈